# Class is defined but Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class not found

Tags: php

I'm experiencing very weird response from PHP with these simple codes:

test3.php:

```
<?php

//my test3.php file

?>
```

test.php:

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/test3.php');

$a = new testing();
echo $a->returnit();

class testing extends test2{
    public function __construct($test=1){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class test2{
    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function returnit(){
        return 'Tester';
    }
}

?>
```

As you can see, it is very simple code and it should run without any problem but look how it throws fatal error sometimes:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'testing' not found

[image: Fatal Error]

PHP and Apache version:

Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)

Server built:   2018-10-10T18:59:25

PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Sep 13 2018 13:45:02) ( NTS )

Zend Engine v3.2.0 with Zend OPcache v7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Why is this happening? Is it something related to the codes?

Edit:
If I create instance after those classes it works without problem, but I want to know why this happening sometimes (not always) and why that error goes away with a single refresh?

Comment: Can you show me your "test3.php" file's code?

Comment: @AmitRajput It is in the question and video. It has just that one comment line.

Comment: first call `class`, then `new` ...

Comment: But you have not written code for class in test3.php.

Comment: @AmitRajput It doesn't matter in this case. This is just a sample for showing how the fatal error happening sometimes without any changing and even this sample codes looks legit for creating instance. I wonder why this is happening "sometimes"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) states:

> Classes should be defined before instantiation (and in some cases this is a requirement)

and it would appear this is one of those cases (unfortunately the manual doesn't give any guidance as to exactly what the cases are). Note that if you simply alter the order of the class definitions the code works fine too. [Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/tvKFd)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is strange as your code works perfect on my local

I tried to make some minor changes as follows. can you try this way

**test.php**

```
  <?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/test3.php');

class testing extends test2{
    public function __construct($test=1){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class test2{
    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function returnit(){
        return 'Tester';
    }
}

?>
```

**test3.php**

```
<?php

$a = new testing();
echo $a->returnit();

?>
```